# Database performance discussion over hasMany table

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have hasMany table that records transactions of purchases of users.

I'm also about to write some code logics so it picks up the latest account balance based on the row that has the latest created date for the same user_id.

I was wondering if I should also record the latest account balance on the users table aswell after each transaction?

Would this help in terms of mysql performances or should I not really bother about it as it's not that significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you create a calculated field like the one you are thinking about, you introduce redundant data in your system. Sometimes the software developer chooses to do so in benefit of performance, so what you need to measure here is the cost of maintaining redundant data vs. the average time savings you achieve with the calculated field approach.

I would consider the following:

- How big will the transactions relation grow?
- How often will new transactions be created?
- How many sources of new transactions there will be?
- Can you speed up the query? (for instance a date search is slower than an integer search, can you use the id, supposing the bigger the newer?)

There is nothing intrinsicly bad in using calculated fields, just be aware of the risks it involves.

Cheers